# CSV file: how to delete the first rows of a file with python using pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, data-cleaning

Suppose I have this CSV file: how to delete the first three rows of it before reading it as a pandas dataframe?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzPMK.png)

So far I have done it manually.

I attach the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

path = r"     .csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', decimal=",", low_memory=False)
df = df.iloc[17120:]

print(df.head())
#print(len(df.index))

dens = df['Density']
dens = dens.astype(float)
dens_sub = dens[68800:]
plt.plot(dens_sub)
plt.ylim([1040,1055])
plt.show()
```

Comment: add the `skiprows=3` parameter